# jquery: how to wait until ajax call would be completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an anchor on my page that leads to some other website.

I want to keep track on clicking that anchor, so I wrote a little click handler.

```
<a href="https://othersite.com" class="js-button">Leave</a>
```

and there's javascript code...

```
$(".js-button").on("click", function() {
    var name = $(this).data("name");
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            url : 'statscript.php',
            type : 'post',
            data : 'name=' + name,
            success : function(response) {                  
            }
        })
    ).then(); 
});
```

Though it should wait for an ajax to load and only after that leave the page, in fact it doesn't work. The `statscript.php` doesn't even start working, and user leaves the page.

So if I alter the string with then to

```
).then(alert('hey');
```

the php script works fine because it looks like it has time to work.

So what am I doing wrong with the `wait` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The closest solution to your code would be:**

You should use **e.preventDefault()** to prevent the default action of the a tag.

You should also redirect the user on **complete**. if you got error in your analytics system, he doesn't need to know that.

You should do it like that:

```
$(".js-button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $(this).data("name"),
        href = $(this).attr("href");

    $.ajax({
        url : 'statscript.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : 'name=' + name,
        complete: function () {
            alert('Hey!');
            // if you want to redirect the user after the statistics sent:
            //window.location.href = href;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close to the answer: There is a done function called like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
}).done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
        console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two problems. One Jnn Mgdls responded to - the AJAX done callback on the promise is to be used.

The second problem may be related to the anchor's event causing a navigation away from the page, and you may need to prevent the default behavior - http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the default browser action and then manually redirect the user:

```
$(".js-button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).data("name"),
        href = this.href;
    $.ajax({
        url : 'statscript.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : 'name=' + name,
        success : function(response) {
            document.location.href = href;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I'm also curious. Is it some kind of bad code style?

Answer (score -1):

There is a function called `ajaxComplete()`

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  alert('Ajax done');
});
```